# JDBC driver and terminal classpath

Tags: java, jdbc, terminal, classpath

I'm trying to connect to a sql database made through mysql_workbench on a linux machine. I currently code through terminal using text editors because that's what I feel comfortable in.

My DatabaseConnection class has the following code, mostly with `System.out.println`'s to try and find the problem cause:

```
final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";

final String user = "root";
final String pass = "pass";

Connection connection;
Statement statement;

public DatabaseConnection(){

}

public void connect(){
    System.out.println("Entering method");
    try {
        System.out.println("Attempting to load driver");
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER); 
        System.out.println("Driver Loaded");        
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, user, pass);
        System.out.println("Connection established");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println(" statement made");
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("show databases");
        System.out.println("statement executed");

        while(resultSet.next()){
            System.out.println(resultSet.next());
        }
        System.out.println("finished printing result set");

        statement.close();
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("Connection Error");         
        sqle.getErrorCode();
    }

}
}
```

I also have a `Test` class to test this:

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection();
        connection.connect();
    }
}
```

Currently when running it in terminal my commands are:

```
javac -cp .:/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar Test.java
```

(In my top folder containing the .java files, I have a lib subfolder containing my jdbc driver)

That compiles fine. Next I run it using

```
java -cp .:/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar Test
```

And I get the following error:

```
java -cp .:/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar Test
Entering method
Attempting to load driver
Error: unable to load driver class!
```

So it looks to be it isn't loading the driver in the `Class.forName()` method and is failing. Could somebody possibly help with explaining why and possible solutions?

In mysql_workbench, I think the database is up and running since I am able to query it in the workbench query command line to show the databases and tables, which are currently empty.

Comment: Perhaps try adding a period between the colon and the slash, e.g. `java -cp .:./lib/ ...` ?

Comment: Thank you, it connected. Post as an answer and i'll point you up. Massive thanks!!

Comment: Just a side note: It is no longer necessary to use `Class.forName` to load a JDBC driver, Java will automatically load the drivers one the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java was unable to find the JAR file for the MySQL JDBC driver because the `-cp` argument in

```
java -cp .:/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar Test
```

specifies two (colon-separated) locations:

1. `.`
2. `/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar`

The second location is interpreted as an *absolute path*. To have it interpreted as a *relative path* it should start with a period (`.`), i.e.,

```
java -cp .:./lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar Test
```